# is there a quick fix to a broken shutter?

Tags: repair, equipment-damage, shutter

I was cleaning my camera sensor with Q-tips because the dust on my sensor couldn't be removed with air. While cleaning it, the camera turned off and the shutter closed. I was startled and take my hands off on the sensor. Now my camera cannot be used because of a broken shutter. Does anyone know a quick fix ? I'll be needing the camera 8 days from now .

Comment: Q-tips are BAD for cameras... the tips are not meant for delicate electronics, let alone the sensor...

Answer (score 5):

A broken shutter is a repair-depot problem. You won't be able to fix it yourself (or quickly). It'll have to go to the manufacturer.

your best bet is to get it into the manufacturer to get a quote on the repair, and to look into renting a body for the upcoming event from one a rental place (I normally use borrowlenses.com, but also like lensrental.com)

I know that's not the answer you like, and this is going to cost you both for the rental and the repair, but that's the reality in a situation like this.